# Problema Left join mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Necesito hacer un `left join` en MySql y no me esta resultando. Tengo 4 tablas: `articulos`, `subcategoria`, `categoria` y `ventas`. Quiero que se muestren todos los artículos independiente que tengan ventas o no.

Cada articulo tiene una subcategoria y una categoría respectivamente. Y trato de mostrar las ventas filtradas por categoría. esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```sql
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    B.FECHA, 
    B.TOTAL
FROM
    ARTICULOS A,
    SUBCATEGORIA C,
    CATEGORIA D
        LEFT JOIN
    VENTAS B ON A.IDARTICULO = B.FK_IDARTICULO
WHERE
        A.FK_IDSUBCATEGORIA = C.ID_SUBCATEGORIA
    AND C.FK_IDCATEGORIA = D.ID_CATEGORIA
    AND D.ID_CATEGORIA = 1
```

Esto solo muestra resultados para los articulos que tienen ventas.
Como lo puedo hacer??
gracias

Comment: podrias completas las estructuras de ambas tablas

Comment: Tu consulta no debería filtrar artículos que sólo tengan ventas. Quizás todos los artículos de la seccion 1 tienen ventas

Comment: Veo que la consulta y por extensión la pregunta cambiaron completamente. Cuidado con eso. Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos poder confiar que la información es la correcta. La sugerencia sigue siendo válida, por favor incluye un script que nos sirva de [mcve]. Lo mas probable es que el problema no tenga nada que ver con tu `LEFT JOIN`, sino con tus otros joins. Adicionalmente, te sugiero de no mezclar joins implícitos y explicítos como lo estás haciendo. Siempre usa joins explícitos.

Comment: aparte de los consejos de @sstan, revisa que en efecto hayan artículos de la categoría 1 que no tengan ventas, porque nuevamente tu consulta no está filtrando por ventas

Comment: quise simplificar mi pregunta, pero en realidad esta consulta es la que tengo que hacer

Comment: Entiendo lo de querer simplificar la pregunta, y tiene sentido. Pero simplificado o no, la pregunta no es útil si no nos das lo que se necesita para reproducir tu problema. Tu piensas que el problema está con el `LEFT JOIN` y por eso enfocastes la atención a ese detalle en la pregunta, y tal vez omitistes otros detalles pertinentes que no pensabas que lo eran. Pero a menudo, el que pregunta está equivocado en cuanto a la causa real del problema. Para evitar ese tipo de confusión por interpretar mal la causa del problema, siempre es mejor incluir un [mcve], lo que todavía espero que hagas.

Comment: A tu consulta le falta, a mi parecer al menos JOIN en dos tablas. Los JOIN no se hacen simplemente porque tengas claves foráneas en las tablas, se necesita que las tablas estén presentes. ¿Cómo piensas unir cuatro tablas A, B, C, D usando un solo JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta primero hacer una consulta sin el `where`, quizás esa condición afecte el resultado final:

```
SELECT A.*,B.FECHA,B.TOTAL
FROM ARTICULOS A
LEFT JOIN VENTAS B ON A.IDARTICULO=B.FK_IDARTICULO
```

También puedes revisar la BD, para ver si en realidad tienes registros en Artículos que no tengan ventas relacionadas.

Answer (score 1):

Y así?

```
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    B.FECHA, 
    B.TOTAL
FROM
    ARTICULOS A 
INNER JOIN SUBCATEGORIA C ON A.FK_IDSUBCATEGORIA = C.ID_SUBCATEGORIA 
INNER JOIN CATEGORIA D ON C.FK_IDCATEGORIA = D.ID_CATEGORIA 
LEFT JOIN VENTAS B ON A.IDARTICULO = B.FK_IDARTICULO
```

Comment: tal como dices funciona y muestra todos los registros, pero a la hora de hacer un where D.ID_CATEGORIA=X no muestra nada cuando elijo una categoria que no tienen ventas

Comment: Si pones un Where de CATEGORIA=X y no hay datos, que crees que la consulta mostrará?... pues eso, nada.

Comment: no se supone que deberia mostrar la lista de articulos y los campos total y fecha en null? esa es la gracia de left join?

Comment: Claro, pero el filtro de categoria no se hace desde el WHERE, por que ahi filtras desde consulta y no trae datos, necesitas hacerlo despues (o HAVING o desde el mismo SELEC)

Answer (score 0):

Dada tu consulta, la mejor forma es utilizar un `right join` (aunque raro parezca), sino, la otra opción es invertir el `left join` (ventas al lado izquierdo de la relación).

Comment: Hola José. Siendo que le he estado dando duro a otro usuario por su(s) respuesta(s) incorrecta(s), lo justo es que lo haga aquí también :) Un right join o un left join invertido no tiene sentido. Eso significaría que quieres las ventas, tengan o no articulos asociados.  Eso no es lo que OP busca.  OP quiere los articulos, tengan o no ventas.  Por lo que el orden del `LEFT JOIN` tal como lo tiene ya es correcto. Su problema es otro.

Answer (score -2):

Intentalo así:

```
 SELECT 
A.*, 
B.FECHA, 
B.TOTAL
 FROM
ARTICULOS A,
SUBCATEGORIA C,
CATEGORIA D
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
VENTAS B ON A.IDARTICULO = B.FK_IDARTICULO
 WHERE
A.FK_IDSUBCATEGORIA = C.ID_SUBCATEGORIA
AND C.FK_IDCATEGORIA = D.ID_CATEGORIA
AND D.ID_CATEGORIA = 1
```

En vez de LEFT utiliza OUTER esto te traera tanto los que coinciden como los que no coinciden.

Comment: De dónde apareció la tabla `NAME`??, y qué pasó con las condiciones de los joins implícitos?

Comment: No es una tabla NAME es el nombre de las tablas al cual les asigno los alias de C Y D y estaba intentando hacer sus JOIN en las condiciones.

Comment: Sí veo que le asignas alias `C` y `D`, pero `NAME` lo estás usando como una tabla

Comment: ¿Ya te quedo claro?

Comment: Vaya actitud cuando tu respuesta estaba completamente mala. En todo caso, tu nuevo código no va a solucionar el problema del op

Comment: OP no menciona que quiere obtener los articulos aun sino tiene subcategorias o categorias.  Solo si no hay ventas.  Por lo que no estoy seguro si los left joins adicionales son correctos. Aunque es enteramente posible que OP no tiene claro lo que quiere. es dificil saber sin ver los datos y el resultado deseado.

Comment: todos los articulos tienen su relacion con subc, y categorias, pero no todos tienen ventas

Comment: Entonces podrias usar inner en subc y categorias que es donde si tinenes relación asegurda y left en ventas que es donden no todos tienen.

Comment: ...que es exactamente lo que OP ya hace, solo que con una sintaxis distinta.

Comment: No existe la sintaxis `OUTER JOIN` así no mas en MySQL. Y si estabas pensando en un `FULL OUTER JOIN`, que realmente no veo como aplica aquí, tampoco existe en MySQL. Disculpa mi franqueza sin filtros, pero pareces estar disparando para todos los lados con la forma como vas modificando la respuesta intentando todo lo que se te ocurre. Tal vez sería ventajoso probar con una consulta de prueba antes de proponerla.

Comment: Lo siento me falto la sentencia es LEFT OUTER JOIN y estoy tratando de localizar un ejemplo donde lo utilice donde requeria traer datos de registros que tuviera o no dicho dato, y sobre tu ópinion de mis respuesta no voy a decir absolutamente nada.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` es exactamente lo mismo que `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Son sinónimos.

Comment: Pero cambian los resultados al unir más de dos tablas, pase por ese mismo problema y mejor da tu una solución si no te parecen las demas.

Comment: No hay diferencia. Pero si tienes algún script que demuestra lo contrario, con gusto me trago mis palabras. Y, en efecto, estoy deseoso de ayudar a OP con una buena solución, pero solo se puede hacer una vez que OP comparta una script que sirva de [mcve]. De lo contrario, estaría especulando y/o adivinando. Y eso no sería muy útil.

Comment: gracias muchachos, creo que mi respuesta va por lo que dice roy mas arriba, pero con el problema que indiqué ahi